# How to create a dynamic array from an aarry

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to create an ARRAY like this:

```
$myData = array (
    'gallery' => array (
        0 => array (
            'title' => 'Bild 1',
            'image' => 'https://mysite.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IMG_8797.jpg',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I am using wordpress with Wedevs WPUserFrontendPro Form. In this form, I upload images for a gallery. The image IDs are stored in a custom field. Something like 2622, 56565, 44343, 3434.

Now I try to create an array from this string.

```
$bilderGalerie = explode( ',', $string );
```

I tried this:

```
$myData = array (
    'gallery' =>
    for( $i = 0;$i < count( $bilderGalerie );$i ++ ) {
        array (
            $i => array (
                'title' => 'Bild 1 Nummer'.$bilderGalerie[$i],
                'image' =>  wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bilderGalerie[$i], 'thumbnail' )
            ),
        ),
    }
);
```

And I get this: "syntax error, unexpected '}'"

Any suggestions?
Thanks so much,
Denis

Comment: @emma isnt this the closing } for the FOR loop?

Comment: But you have a for loop inside an array declaration. That won't work

Comment: @Emma hmm, this get a little tricky now, because 'gallery' is only a small part of this $myData array.

Comment: @Andreas could have worked with `eval()`, but that's not a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned you can not use the for loop inside an array declaration.

As an alternative, what you might do is set the result of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to your value:

```
$myData = [
    "gallery" => array_map(function ($imgId) {
        return array(
            'title' => 'Bild 1 Nummer' . $imgId,
            'image' => wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgId, 'thumbnail')
        );
    }, $bilderGalerie)
];
```

Comment: I dont understand this. What is the function you are calling?

Comment: `$bilderGalerie` is an array of image id's. You can map that collection of image id's using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) turning every entry into an array itself. As the map function has access to the value (the image id), you can use that value and add it to the newly created array.

Comment: I am too stupid, I cant get it work. Even if I make $bilderGalerie static, nothing happens. Nevertheless, thanks for the help.

Comment: This is [an example](https://3v4l.org/Vp0eR) without the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` in it. If you say nothing happens, does that mean you are also not getting an error anymore? What do you see when you do `print_r($myData);` What do you expect to happen? Should `$myData` be assigned to something?

Comment: I tried it static like this

`//static image IDs
$myBilderGalerie = "229,230,231";
$bilderGalerie = explode( ",", $myBilderGalerie );
 
$myData = [
"gallery" => array_map(function ($imgId) {
return array(
'title' => 'Bild 1 Nummer' . $imgId,
'image' => wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgId, 'thumbnail')
);
}, $bilderGalerie)
];`

and it should become `'gallery' => array (
0 => array ('title' => 'Bild 1',
            'image' => 'https://mysite.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IMG_8797.jpg',
        ),
    ),` with 3 images array. Nothing is append to the myData array.

Comment: Not sure why you want to make it static, but I think the syntax should be something like https://3v4l.org/F7I6m

Comment: Your example code does exactly what I like to have. But the code is not added to my ARRAY :-( it is not stored. [link](https://3v4l.org/CUpAA)

Comment: Try putting the `$myData` array first and then set the key `$myData["gallery"] =` to the return value of array_map https://3v4l.org/aPW4u

Comment: As far as I could check it, this does the trick `$myData["gallery"] =` thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't break in and out of the array declaration and execute other code.  Just define the array inside the loop, try `foreach`:

```
foreach($bilderGalerie as $val) {
    $myData['gallery'][] = array(
        'title' => 'Bild 1 Nummer' . $val,
        'image' =>  wp_get_attachment_image_src($val, 'thumbnail'));
}
```

This works well even if `$myData` is already defined as it appends to or creates and appends to  `gallery`.

Comment: Beat me to it... But you have $key? What is that for?

Comment: @Andreas:  I thought they used it but no, I'll remove, thanks!

Comment: @Emma basics are not that great

Comment: @AbraCadaver Now I get a little confused.

I need this complete myData array like:

$myData = array (
'Telefon' => 'test',
'email' => 'test',
'icon' => 'test',
'gallery' => array (
0 => array (
'title' => 'Bild 1',
'image' => 'https://mysite.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IMG_8797.jpg',
),
),
);

Where do I put this foreach loop?

Comment: Doesn't matter, either before or after you add the other stuff to the array.